# How do I prevent a 301 Redirection when a user requests a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been attempting to make a front controller that would ignore existing directories. In some cases, I've been getting 301 redirects where I wish would not occur. I'm using the following `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

At the directory I've been testing this, I have the following setup:

```
test/
.htaccess
index.php
```

If I attempt to query the server, my second example results in a 301 redirect:

```
curl -s server/tes    | Outputs: tes
curl -s server/test   | 301 Redirect; on follow will output: test
curl -s server/test/  | Outputs: test/
```

How can I prevent a 301 from occurring when accessing `server/test`? I feel like I'm missing something pretty trivial here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because `test` is a directory and `mod_dir` module that runs after `mod_rewrite` adds a trailing slash and does a 301 redirect. You can prevent it by adding this line on top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

However keep in mind that it is considered a security risks as it can show directory listing.

You can make this redirect in htaccess itself using this rule:

```
# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: In a situation where I don't mind the security risk (just using it locally), I am still curious about the security implications. I notice the [security warning](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#DirectorySlash) mentions when `mod_autoindex` is active (`Options +Indexes`). Since I have this disable, `Options -Indexes`, will I be fine?

Comment: Yes I think with `Options -Indexes` it should be fine.